# IIS 8.5 does not update a dynamic page (caching is turned off and responseBufferingLimit=0)

Tags: php, caching, iis, iis-8, buffering

I have IIS 8.5 / PHP 5.4 on Windows Server 2012R2.

I have a simple PHP-script that continuously updates the file test.shtm every second (it just writes an increasing number counter to the file):

test_call.php:
        $pctrl_file=fopen("jobs/test.grass-proc",'w');

```
for ($counter=1;$counter<=100;$counter++)
   {if ((fseek($pctrl_file,0)==-1||!fwrite($pctrl_file,$counter))||!fflush($pctrl_file)) 
        echo ('Could not write to file resource');
    sleep(1); //delay 1 sec 
   }   

if (!fclose($pctrl_file)) echo 'Failed to close the file';
```

Caching in IIS is set to 'No caching' for .shtm files. I also tried option "prevent all caching".

In the list of IIS handlers I see that there is a handler for .shtm, so I think .shtm content is not considered static

In the IIS configuration editor I have set ResponseBufferLimit to 0 for both .php and for .shtm

I also tried another file extension .aaa instead of .shtm with .aaa set to plain/text in IIS MimeType list. (It made no change).

I call this PHP script from client browser.
I check how the test.shtm file changes via jquery/ajax using GET (or POST, it does not make change), for reference see code below my message.

In another tab I enter URL to this generated test.shtm file.
I check that test.shtm file really changes using RemoteDesktop, and I confirm that the file on the server changes every second.
However both ajax output and pure page output (pressing F5 on URL to test.shtm in any browser) stop updating after two or three iterations.

There are three peculiarities:

1) When the PHP script finishes, ajax output updates immediately to display "100" as expected, and if I press F5 on test.shtm (after the PHP script has finished) it displays "100" as expected.

2) Exactly at the moment when I open test.shtm file in Notepad using RemoteDesktop, ajax output updates to the current value, and F5 in browser updates the content correcty (but only once, until I open test.shtm on the server once again)

3) issue 2 is true sometimes but not always

To prevent caching in browser I tried adding these HTTP response headers is IIS configuration:
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate
Expires: 0
It changed nothing.

Regarding the purpose for which this test was made, I cannot add anything else inside the generated file, it should contain just a number.

Exactly the same scripts work well under Windows 7 + Apache 2.2 (with default caching and buffering settings) on my local computer.
What have I done wrong in IIS configuration (or wherever else)?

ajax checker (I also tried calling test_call.php explicitly => no change):

```
    <html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="../jquery_min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="answer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function read_pctl()
{$.ajax({type: "GET",
         cache:false,
         mimeType: "text/plain",
         url: 'jobs/test.shtm', //also tried adding ?_='+Math.random(),
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         success: function(pctl_data) {$('#control').html('updated: '+pctl_data); },
         error: function(obj,msg,err) {console.log('TEST pctl error, file "jobs/test.grass-proc" : '+msg+' - '+err);}
         });
}

  $('#answer').html("<div id='control' style='border:blue 1px solid'>Place for updated numbers</div>"); //display progress message

  pctl_updater=setInterval(read_pctl,1000); //start updating control-container

  $.ajax({type: "POST",
          url: 'test_call.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {$('#answer').html("<span class='error'>Finished<br></span>"); }
          error: function(obj,msg,err) {$('#answer').html("<span class='error'>TEST call error:<br></span>"+msg+' - '+err); }
         });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, first line in the first code should be :
`$pctrl_file=fopen("jobs/test.shtm",'w');`

I don't know how to edit my question:(

Comment: I could bypass this problem by replacement of .shtm file by a .php file and putting `<?php echo $counter; ?>` inside instead of just a counter. But I would like to understand the reason of such behaviour of IIS and I am seeking for a general solution. I could not find differences between .shtm and .php files in IIS settings, except a handler. Also, MimeType for .php is at all missing in IIS MimeType list, but php scripts work fine.